# Encryption using L2CAP Connections over channels

Tags: security, bluetooth-lowenergy, l2cap

In Bluetooth Low Energy, does anyone know if the Security Manager can be used with L2CAP connections over channels?  Meaning when I transfer data over a custom L2CAP channel, is there anyway to encrypt it with the Security Manager?

The Security Manager is a service on top of L2CAP in the BLE stack so I suspect it cannot.  Just wondering if someone had a definitive answer.  Thanks so much!

Just hoping for an answer and some explanation of how the responder came to that conclusion

Answer (score 1):

The encryption is performed by the Link Layer and affects the whole BLE communication. The Security Manager is only used to initiate encryption, as well as performing pairing.

So yes, start encryption either by performing pairing or by using the LTK from an existing bond. Then, all communication, including L2CAP CoC and GATT communication, will be encrypted, for this connection.